# How will i able check trained model prediction on new data

Tags: machine-learning, svm, naivebayes

I build a model with the help of Scikit library in python and trained and test using cross-validation method.But now i want to test the model accuracy with more new data,how can i able to test with new data after building it.

Comment: You have a better chance of getting an answer to that at http://stats.stackexchange.com/
But they will also ask you: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

After you train your data you can use predict() multiple times. So you can test new data with same model. You can also save the model you have built using pickle.
Refer to this in their documentation 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Any way I got my solution of given problem.but your provided link is also very use full for me for later task.Thanks